# Populate an asp.net Gridview dynamically with List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a list of Employee records being returned in a List format. How can I populate a gridview dynamically?

```
ePremiumSubscriber.Subscriber PremSubData = new ePremiumSubscriber.Subscriber();
List<ePremiumSubscriber.Subscriber> premSubList = new List<ePremiumSubscriber.Subscriber>();

ePremiumCustomerDAL.SearchPremSubscriberData(premSubList, sqlQuery);  


DataTable dtSearchResults = new DataTable();
dtSearchResults.Columns.Add("psLastName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dtSearchResults.Columns.Add("psFirstName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
```

Comment: By Default, AutoGenerateColumns="True", and the grid creates the columns according to the data source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop a GridView control you asp.net page and then you can do it his way

```
GridView1.DataSource = dtSearchResults ;

GridView1.DataBind();
```